# Staff information Tracker help

Tags: 2010, user-information-list

I’ve been tasked to look at using SharePoint 2010 to better manage staff information. Staff information can include: Personal Information (name, address, phone email etc), Next of Kin information (same things), Training courses, competencies (when due to renew). Currently all of this information is managed in about 16 tabs in an excel document.

I know I can put all of this in one gigantic list and filter it by views, but I wonder if there was a better way or perhaps a 3rd party COTS webpart? If we went down a COTS webpart solution, it would have to be something with a fair amount of user flexibility and administrator set fields.

The intent here is for staff to manage their own information and keep it up-to-date and for managers to better understand what courses staff have done, what they want do to, what competencies need to be actions.

I’d appreciate any thoughts you guys have on how best to tackle this problem.